JQ Cannot iterate over null
I am trying to create a jq that is dynamic in returning data.
User Story: I have data with many fields and not named like I want. I want to be able to based on the data and schema transform the data.
Example:
JSON
  "inputArray": [
    {
      "objective_id": "ac-1_obj.a-1",
      "description": "an access control policy is developed and documented;",
      "framework_id": 1,
      "domain_id": "ac",
      "domaintitle": "Access Control",
      "id": 0,
      "control_id": "ac-1",
      "controltitle": "Policy and Procedures"
    },
    {
      "objective_id": "ac-1_obj.a-2",
      "description": "the access control policy is disseminated to {{ insert: param, ac-01_odp.01 }};",
      "framework_id": 1,
      "domain_id": "ac",
      "domaintitle": "Access Control",
      "id": 0,
      "control_id": "ac-1",
      "controltitle": "Policy and Procedures"
    },
    {
      "objective_id": "ac-1_obj.a-3",
      "description": "access control procedures to facilitate the implementation of the access control policy and associated controls are developed and documented;",
      "framework_id": 1,
      "domain_id": "ac",
      "domaintitle": "Access Control",
      "id": 0,
      "control_id": "ac-1",
      "controltitle": "Policy and Procedures"
    }
  ],
  "schema": [
    { "new": "objective", "input": "objective_id" },
    { "new": "framework", "input": "framework_id" },
    { "new": "control", "input": "control_id" },
    { "new": "title", "input": "controltitle" },
    { "new": "description", "input": "description" }
  ]
}

JQ
  inputArray: [
    .inputArray[] |
    reduce (.schema[] | {new: .new, input: .input}) as $map (
      {}; 
      .[$map.new] = .[$map.input]
    )
  ]
}

Error
jq: error (at /tmp/data.json:40): Cannot iterate over null (null) undefined


schema is what it seems to be mad about.
I have tested that .schema is available
I have added ? to the end of .schema and values are empty



What is your expected output?

The objects inside the inputArray array don't have a schema field, so accessing it evaluates to null, which you can't iterate over (with .schema[]).

The error you are encountering is related to referencing the top level schema object while iterating through the contents of inputArray without having a proper reference back to it.
So, you need to be able to get the value of the current item with the key (item[ that maps to the key in the schema.
Try this:
{
  transformedArray: (
    [.inputArray[] as $item |
      reduce .schema[] as $s (
        {}; 
        . + { ($s.new): $item[$s.input] }
      )
    ]
  )
}

$item is the current item being iterated over in inputArray.
$s is the schema, then $s.new is the new key that replaces the old key $s.input.
The value is then obtained with $item[$s.input]


Thank you very much. Exactly what was needed:)
